# gspread data does not appear in Google Sheet

Tags: gspread, r-googlesheets

I'm trying to write sensor data to a google sheet.  I was able to write to this same sheet a year or so ago but I am active on this project again and can't get it to work.  I believe the Oauth has changed and I've updated my code for that change.

In the below code, I get no errors, however no data in entered in the GoogleSheet.  Also, If I look at GoogleSheets, the "last opened" date does not reflect the time my program would/should be writing to that google sheet.
I've tried numerous variations and I'm just stuck.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-- developed with Python 3.4.2
# External Resources 
import time
import sys
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import traceback
# Initialize gspread
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('MyGoogleCode.json',scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# Start loop ________________________________________________________________
samplecount = 1
while True:
    data_time = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    row = ([samplecount,data_time]) 

    # Append to Google sheet_
    try:
        if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
            credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
        GoogleDataFile = client.open('DataLogger')
        #wks = GoogleDataFile.get_worksheet(1)
        wks = GoogleDataFile.get_worksheet(1)
        wks.append_row([samplecount,data_time])
        print("worksheets", GoogleDataFile.worksheets()) #prints ID for both sheets
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
    print ("samplecount  ", samplecount, row)  
    samplecount += 1
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue.  I've changed 3 things to get gspread working:

1. Downloaded a newly created json file (probably did not need this step)
2. With the target worksheet open in chrome, I "shared" it with the email address found in the JSON file.
3. In the google developers console, I enabled "Drive API"

However, the code in the original post will not refresh the token.  It will stop working after 60 minutes.

The code that works (as of July 2017) is below.
The code writes to a google sheet named "Datalogger"
It writes to the sheet shown as Sheet2 in the google view.
The only unique information is the name of the JSON file

Hope this helps others.

Jon

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -- developed with Python 3.4.2
#
# External Resources __________________________________________________________
import time
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import traceback

# Initialize gspread credentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('MyjsonFile.json',scope)
headers = gspread.httpsession.HTTPSession(headers={'Connection': 'Keep-Alive'})
client = gspread.Client(auth=credentials, http_session=headers)
client.login()
workbook = client.open("DataLogger")
wksheet = workbook.get_worksheet(1)

# Start loop ________________________________________________________________
samplecount = 1
while True:
    data_time = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    row_data = [samplecount,data_time]
    if credentials.access_token_expired:
        client.login()        
    wksheet.append_row(row_data)
    print("Number of rows in out worksheet  ",wksheet.row_count)
    print ("samplecount  ", samplecount, row_data)  
    print()
    samplecount += 1
    time.sleep(16*60)
```